# Forecasting with two or more causal factors using the Holt-Winters method (in R)

Tags: r, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

Is there something similar to the Holt-Winters forecasting method in R, which can be used to model two or more explanatory factors?

Comment: What do you mean by "a forecast with 2 or more factors"?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa i have my data..and there are 2 or more factors where i want to import in an order.the factors affect my data..so i guess that i have to include them to have a better forecast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could in principle do one of two things:

1. Extend the Exponential Smoothing framework to include additional components for your causal variables, which get updated along with the level, trend and seasonal components.
2. Regress your time series on your causal factors, the model residuals using Exponential Smoothing.

There is no implementation in R that I know of. [Here are Rob Hyndman's thoughts on the topic, along with pointers to papers where he did something along these lines.](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/ets-regressors/)

Alternatively, you could use ARIMAX modeling, i.e., ARIMA with eXternal or eXplanatory variables. Look at the `forecast` package and the `auto.arima()` function. You can feed external information into its `xreg` parameter.